# show that trigonometry inequality holds

Tags: trigonometry

show that trigonometry inequality holds for $\displaystyle x\in\left(0, \frac{\pi}{12}\right)$

$$ \frac{\cos{x}}{\sin^2{x}(\cos{x}-\sin{x})}>8$$

I tried to swich all to sines but it didn't help me

Comment: Do you know how to bound $\cos x$, $\sin^2 x$ and $\cos x - \sin x$ on this interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=\tan x$, then $0<t<\tan (\pi/12)=2-\sqrt{3}$ and the formula would be $\frac{1}{1-t}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)$, which is equal to $ \frac{2}{1-t}+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}$. So the formular is greater than $1/t^2>(2+\sqrt{3})^2>8$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The inequality is equivalent to:

$$\cos x > 8\sin^2 x \cos x - 8sin^3 x$$
$$\cos x > 4\sin x \sin 2x - 8sin^3 x$$
$$\cot x > 4\sin 2x - 8\sin^2 x$$

Now since $4\sin 2x$ grows faster thatn $8\sin^2 x$, the maximum of the left side is when $x = \frac \pi{12}$. Also the minimum of the left hand side is at that point since cotangent is decreasin function.

Use the formula for half-angles to calculate the values for $\cot \frac \pi{12}$ and $\sin \frac\pi{12}$